# htaccess force redirect when language not matches

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect when user write a language which not match like `example.com/mvc/fr` or when write index instead of language like `example.com/mvc/index.php` 
to `example.com/mvc/en`

Here is what I tried:

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /mvc/


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*example.com [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^ar [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/mvc/ar/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/mvc/en/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/mvc/de/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|ar|de)/
RewriteRule ^ /mvc/ [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: When you request `/mvc/en` (or `/mvc/en/`, or `/mvc/en/…`), the request URI doesn’t _start with_ `/en/` as your RewriteCond demands …

Comment: Yes, what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Uhm, what I just said you’re doing wrong …? Your RewriteCond would only match, if the user requested `/en/…`

Comment: FYI, rewriting based on the Accept-Language like that is really bad. Even if you offered links to switch to a different language version, I would still get redirected back to the language version specified in the Accept-Language header (and I might not be in control of that, for example if I am just visiting your site from a crappy little internet cafe in fook-knows-where …)